# Android php webservice access error

Tags: php, android, json

I want to access a simple php web service from Android application. To test this I have created this very first php web service with json encoding and hosted it in WAMPSERVER running on local host.

```
<?php
$string='{"name":"John Adams"}';
echo json_encode($string);
?>
```

To access this web service I have created an Android http client as follows.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class JsonV01Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/json/phpjson.php");
    try {
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

       JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(str).nextValue();

       String name = object.getString("name");

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tv.append(name);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }
}
```

I added internet permissions, but this gives only blank screen. I know this problem is very simple but I can't get it solved. Please help, what is the error and how I can correct this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can any one point me to a good simple tutorial ? because all I found were very advanced and difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

that How I always do it!

```
                try {
URL url2 = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/2010/phpfile.php");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url2.openStream()));
                String line ="";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                    values = new String [ja.length()];          

                    // fetching data
                    for (int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++ ) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);


                        int id = jo.getInt("id");
                        String name = jo.getString("name");

                    }

                }


            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return "Interrupted";

            }
```

Comment: you have to echo the encodable Json object in your php file first!! I have used this code millions of times.

Comment: error was in the php web service..web service has to change like this::
<?php
$data = array('name' => 'John Adams', 'Age' => '24'); 
print (json_encode($data)); 
?>
Thanks!